# What cause the capital-output ratio to be low in developing countries?

Tags: political-economy, development-economics, capital, input-output

I'm now studying economic development and I wonder what is the causes of low ICOR in developing countries and high ICOR in advanced countries.

Because it's about economic development so I need some reason which is both logical and some tend to be conspiracy theories.
Thank you guys. pls help me

Comment: If you are asking about _incremental_ capital-output ratio you should make this clear in the title.  Capital-output ratio (ie ratio of total capital to total output) is a rather different concept.